# Munin graphs picking different data from munin-nodes

Tags: ubuntu, vps, munin, graph

I am using Munin graphs with multiple VPSes at the moment and most of them are running Ubuntu version 10.04 LTS or greater.

The issue is, im installing munin-node from the the default repo BUT some VPSes are showing Apache graphs in munin-server and some are not (all servers have Apache installed so it should pick Apache)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the plugin/plugins you want aren't enabled.

You can enable a plugin by creating a symlink to /usr/share/munin/plugins/*plugin_name* in /etc/munin/plugins/ on each of the servers running munin-node.

E.g. to enable apache_accesses, apache_processes and apache_volume, run (as root):

```
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_accesses /etc/munin/plugins/apache_accesses
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_processes /etc/munin/plugins/apache_processes
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_volume /etc/munin/plugins/apache_volume
```

and then `/etc/init.d/munin-node restart` so that munin-node sees the new plugins.

If it still won't work, then maybe you don't have the Apache server-status page enabled on those particular VPSes (all three munin apache plugins require it).

I prefer to use nginx so I can't give you specific instructions from experience, but [this page has a nice-looking guide to setting up mod_status on Ubuntu](http://scottlinux.com/2011/09/01/apache-server-status-with-mod_status/). Unless you've got a good reason, you should restrict it to localhost like that page says (it can be considered a security vulnerability to leave it open to the world since it shows information about your server, your visitors' IP addresses and the URLs they're accessing.)

Comment: `-bash: cd: /etc/munin/plugins/: No such file or directory`

Comment: You need to run those commands on the servers running munin-node, not the main munin server. I've updated my answer to make that more clear.